# Where in the Mondaiji light novel does the manga diverge?

Tags: mondaiji

At what point in the Mondaiji light novel does the manga jump past the original's material?
I know that chapter 11 of the manga is where the manga jumps ahead, right after the circus arc.

Comment: i do know that volume 2 of the LN is where the anime ends